# Show only column data from a selection in access

Tags: ms-access

I have not used access in over 10 years now so I am slowly trying to get myself back into it but after spending time on the internet I am not sure if what I am looking to do is possible or not so any help would be appreciated.

I have a combo box that has a drop down list with multiple options e.g A, B, C, D, E.

These options are also the headers of columns in table1.

I also have a query set up that has all the columns included and the "Show" checkbox is ticked on all of them. (I can not have 1 checked and the rest unchecked as we will not know which column is needed until the user chooses from the list in the combo box).

When I choose for example option B, I want only the data from column B to be visible in my list box.

There will be around 20 different options in the combo box that correspond with the column headers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event of the combobox to adjust the *RowSource* of the listbox:

```vb
Me!YourListbox.RowSource = "Select " & Me!YourCombobox.Value & " From YourQuery"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It is definatly trying to find something but is coming up blank. I think the problem is that I want to return the information from columns not rows.

Comment: Copy the generated SQL and run it manually in a query to see how to correct.

Comment: I think that it is because I manually typed my column headers when creating the combo box instead of pulling them from the table. I am now looking how to make the combo box drop down list only show the column headers from the table .